Saving an entity with compressed client response and request in Symfony 7
Initial Situation
I have an application in Symfony 7. In this application, I am making external API calls, for which I have an abstract class HttpClient defined. In this class, I use guzzle Client to handle the request. I have an entity for saving external call related information and am using Doctrine for database interactions. The snippet of the entity is below:
#[ORM\Column(name: 'request',type: 'json')]
private array $request;

#[ORM\Column(name: 'response', type: 'json', nullable: true)]
private ?array $response = null;

Until now, I have been saving request and response as plain text. Compressing request does not seem to create any problems, the response compression has proven to be problematic. Below is the snippet of my HttpClient abstract class (I removed the parts which are not relevant to this question), where the entity is created and saved to the database:
$log = [
    'request' => $this->serializer->normalize($request),
];

try {
    $response = $this->client->request(
        $request->getRequestMethod(),
        $request->getUri(),
        $this->prepareGuzzleOptions($request)
    );
    $log['response'] = $this->serializer->decode((string) $response->getBody()->getContents(), 'json');
} catch (GuzzleException $e) {
    $log['response'] = $this->serializer->normalize([$e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString()]);
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    $log['response'] = ["exceptionMessage" => $e->getMessage()];
    throw $e;
} finally {
    $log = $this->serializer->denormalize($log, Log::class);
    $this->em->persist($apiLog);
    $this->em->flush();
    $this->em->clear();
}

Desired outcome
Due to space that they take up, I want to compress them and save them compressed. I want also to be able to uncompress them in database management tool in case I need to troubleshoot something.
Steps taken
I tried changing attribute type to both 'blob' and 'binary', also tried to play around with compressing the request but I can not get it to a 'resource' type and get errors like: The type of the "request" attribute for class must be one of "resource" ("array" given). or The type of the "request" attribute for class must be one of "resource" ("string" given).
I understand what the problem is, but cannot think of a solution of how I could convert the string to a resource in an elegant and technically meaningful way.
If any additional information is needed, I will provide it gladly. Any help will be appreciated.

Do you really need to "save" the request and response in your DB or aren't you looking for the Symfony Cache component ? Because there's a Doctrine adapter. Those work very well to cache HTTP calls.

I do need to save the request and response in the database. Tracking the calls is the main purpose of this all

If tracking the calls is the main purpose, then you need to build some metrics middleware and capture the metrics to a table. Your middleware can then take any data from the response that's blob-able data, call a filesystem object and store it in files where it should be. You can then archive those files at key points in time to reduce overall system size. Any given request/response is going to contain duplicate data, so you're just using your DB as a suitcase at that point, which is not what it is designed for. As it stands you will need to decompress data just to get a metric. Not the tool.

Your problem is you aren't using a door, you're smashing your way through a wall. Take a step back and look at things from the end point of view.
